# I am at the top of the whoosh tag, but why isn't it shown on my job CV?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I am one of the [top answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/whoosh/topusers) in the [whoosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whoosh) tag, yet, I don't see it in my job profile. I see only

- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) top 10%
- [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) & [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) top 30%:

[image]

Are there criteria to eliminate some tags from appearing?

---

Actually the same is true for the [arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arabic) tag; check [the top answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arabic/topusers).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [top x% in \[tag\] : rules for the tag to be taken into account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121074)

Comment: @NormalHuman: But how does that relate when Careers is being folded into Jobs on SO? Votes from whom, at that point?

Comment: The answer on the linked duplicate isn't actually quite correct (at least, it may have been at one time, but it's no longer the case). It's not about votes on a tag, but the number of answers. Specifically, the number of answers by users with a Careers profile (which is the same thing as a CV on SO).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both of those tags are low-traffic. In addition to being in the top 10/20/30% of users for that tag, there are additional criteria for tags to appear on your profile:

- you must have a total answer score over 20 for that tag
- you must have at least 3 answers in that tag
- across all CVs, there must be at least 500 answers in that tag

In your case, the first two criteria are fulfilled for [whoosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whoosh) and [arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arabic), but those tags just aren't common enough yet on CVs for them to be included - they currently have 42 and 261 answers across all CVs.

Comment: I didn't get the third, 500 answers in SO for users having a public job CV?

Comment: 500 answers in SO for users having any kind of CV on our system. It doesn't have to be a public one.

Comment: Is there any reason not all answers are taken into account?